System is occasionnaly not suspending
Every now and then my system is not properly suspending. Shutting the lid, choosing to suspend from the graphic interface or running a command is shutting down the screen, but the system will come back up again after a few seconds.
Running troubleshooting shows that some devices are blocking the system from suspending. What can be done to allow my system to suspend?

It might be that a specific device is blocking your system from suspending, so it comes up again after a few seconds. To avoid this behavior, try disabling some devices that can cause a wake-up so that your system can properly suspend.
Here is what worked in my case:

Try to suspend (also by running the command echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state as root)
Run journalctl -b as root.
Identify entries signalling that a device is blocking the system from shutting down.
In my case, the problematic output was this:

Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: ------------[ DSP dump start ]------------
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware boot failure due to timeout
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: fw_state: SOF_FW_BOOT_IN_PROGRESS (3)
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: ROM status: 0x5, ROM error: 0x0
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: ROM debug status: 0x50000005, ROM debug error: 0x0
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: ROM feature bit enabled
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: ------------[ DSP dump end ]------------
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to boot DSP firmware after resume -5
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): e1000e_pm_suspend+0x0/0xa0 [e1000e] returns -2
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -2
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: failed to suspend async: error -2
Oct 12 16:01:40 Machine kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected


Search for the devices that can wake your device up, or, as it might be the case because of this bug, prevent it from suspending. To do so, look into the content of /proc/acpi/wakeup (e.g. with cat /proc/acpi/wakeup). You should get a list of devices, some of them are disabled signalling that they cannot wake up your machine, others are enabled. My file looks like this:

Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00
XDCI      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.6
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDAS      S4    *enabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
I3C0      S4    *disabled
CNVW      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.3
RP01      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:06.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP10      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:06.1
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TXHC      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.0
TDM0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.2
TDM1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.3
TRP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP1      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP3      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00


Compare the output of devices that blocked suspend to the list of devices. If there are any identifiers referring to a device that is enable, consider disabling them. To do so, edit the text file as a root and replace for this specific device disabled with enabled. (I did so for HDAS).
Try to suspend your machine.

Bonus:
To get an idea of the device which was blocking the suspend, run lspci as root.
In my case, I get:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7d02 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Graphics] (rev 08)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d03 (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e4d (rev 20)
00:06.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7eca (rev 10)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d0d (rev 01)
00:0b.0 Processing accelerators: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake NPU (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7e7f (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e70 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e38 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e03 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 550b (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN770 / PC SN740 256GB / PC SN560 (DRAM-less) NVMe SSD (rev 01)

The problematic device being 00:1f.6, I am concluding that the ethernet controller blocked the system from suspending.
Note : There are of course other problems making it impossible to suspend a system. This is only a contribution designed to be complementary to the already existing explanations.
